# Trying to publish a build to Nuget.org

Tags: azure-devops

I'm new to Azure DevOps; however, what I'm doing seems like it should be straightforward: I simply want to compile a project and publish to NuGet.org.  I'm hitting that many barriers to doing it that I feel that I'm probably mis-using the tool.

I have a build which looks like this:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration) /property:Version=$(Build.BuildNumber)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' 
    artifactName: 'drop'
```

This successfully builds. However, I do get the following warning:

```
##[warning]Directory 'd:\a\1\a' is empty. Nothing will be added to build artifact 'drop'.
```

When I try to deploy, I'm getting errors - the latest of which is:

> No files matched the search pattern.

In dotnet pack, here's the release step for pack:

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet pack'
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/name.project'
```

This is what's currently failing, but the next step is intended to publish to NuGet (for completeness - and incase there's an easier way to do all this):

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet pack'
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/name.project'
```

The release has an artifact, which I've set up as the output from the build (I think); however, I get the error from this:

> No version is available for name.project or the latest version has
>   no artifacts to publish. Please check the source pipeline.

My understanding of how this should work in general is that the Build should hold the steps involved in producing the binaries, etc, whereas the Release should be any steps involved in deploying the built. So, I should be able to take a 'Build' and 'Release' it several times to multiple locations. I feel like this understanding is not in-keeping with the errors that I'm seeing.

Is my understanding correct?

What could I be doing wrong here and, more importantly, what are the methods of diagnosing issues with this?

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: I am a bit confused here. In all my history of publishing a nuget package, I do it in the build process, not the release process. Release is for deploying the bits for actual usage in an environment. You are wanting to create a package for later consumption as part of a build. That isn't a release by the standards of nuget pack and nuget publish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Trying to publish a build to Nuget.org

For the first error, that because you are mising the [Copy Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) task before using the [Publish Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task.

Check the Publish Build Artifacts task, you can view this task is used to **publish build artifacts to Azure Pipelines, TFS, or a file share**.

But after build the project/solution, the output are stored on the build agent, rather than the artifacts. So we need to add a `copy task` before `PublishBuildArtifacts` to copy the files from output to the artifacts:

```
steps:
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  enabled: false
```

For the second error, you should specify the project in the **repos**  instead of `System.DefaultWorkingDirectory`, where is use to build the project, change the Path to csproj in the repos:

```
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet pack'
  inputs:
    command: pack
    packagesToPack: NetCoreDemo/NetCoreDemo/NetCoreDemo.csproj
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You man need to provide the `--output` argument for `dotnet build`. Add the following

```
--output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

so the command should look something like this.

```
dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration) /property:Version=$(Build.BuildNumber) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
```

this will put the output into the **Artifact Staging Directory (d:\a\1\a)**
 which will include the `*.nupkg` file.

I am assuming you are using the new CSProj format and you are supplying the properties for the NuGet package and have the `<GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>` property already set. If so the `*.nupkg` file should be in the output directory that you define in the dotnet build command. Then you don't need to use `dotnet pack`. In the release definition you just need to use the NuGet task and use push command to push the package to your NuGet Feed.

Use this [blog post](https://kasunkodagoda.com/2019/03/05/implementing-a-build-and-release-pipeline-for-open-source-nuget-packages-using-azure-pipelines/) as reference. It does not have the full details since its focusing only on few aspects of the entire process. but it should be helpful to get the build aspect correct.